# how to upload a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload

HTML code:-

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:3000/api" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in nodeJS is

```
app.post('/api',function (req, res) {
    //JSON.stringify(req.files);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files));
    var file = req.files.file;
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
});
```

I want to print the details of the-files.

I am getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
>      at /Users/mAddy/Desktop/check1/server.js:27:25

Comment: And you've included middleware to parse multipart data, like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) or something similar ?

Comment: what about using body-parser

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: If you look at the [Github page for BodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), the first line is *"This does not handle multipart bodies"*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), as express/connect no longer supports multipart on its own. Also, use the `post` method on the express/connect app.

After [installing multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#installation):

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});

app.post('/api', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {

  res.sendStatus(200);

});
```